# access dynamic properties of a dynamic class and set value in C#

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection

I am try to create an extension method which accept the parameter as type IEnumerable and try to produce some html string based on number of column and rows count like below

```
public static  string Grid<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection )
{
    string template = "<div class='loadTemplateContainer' style='display: block;'>"+
                      "<div class='headercontainer'>";
    PropertyInfo[] classProperties = typeof (T).GetProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo classProperty in classProperties)
    {
        template = template + "<div class='column style='width: 200px;'>" + 
        classProperty.Name + "</div>";
    }
    template = template + "</div><table class='allTemplateTable'><tbody>";
    string rowTemplate = "";
    foreach (dynamic item in collection)
    {
        rowTemplate = rowTemplate + "<tr>";
        foreach (PropertyInfo classProperty in classProperties)
        {
            var currentProperty = classProperty.Name;      
        }
    }       
}
```

i want to get value for each property of an item from the collection by property name. how can i achieve it?

Comment: T is dynamic.user can pass any type of class

Comment: i want to get value of each property value by property name.hope you understand my requirement

Comment: T is not `dynamic` in the sense that c# uses the keyword dynamic. It is of a known type at compile time and the phrasing should be "T is generic" but that is obvious from context. You might have meant to clarify that is is unconstrained too.

Comment: I'm not sure if i get it correctly but do you mean [PropertyInfo.GetValue Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b05d59ty(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done by something like:

```
public static string Grid<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection)
{
    ...........
    ...........

    foreach (T item in collection)
    {
        foreach (var p in classProperties )
        {
            string s = p.Name + ": " + p.GetValue(item, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It may be worth stressing that `dynamic` is unnecessary here since you know the type is `T` (even though that is generic it is still not dynamic).

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using dynamic and everything is set at run-time - you can consider using reflection. I see you already used `PropertyInfo` so maybe you can extend it like this:

```
public static object GetPropValue(object src, string propName)
{
    return src.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(src, null);
}
```

and use in the Iterator to get the value you need.